# .append() adding 2 values and deleting 1 previous value

Tags: python, list

Hi I've been trying to figure out why in this code 'permutations.append(lst)' is not only appending twice, but also deleted the first term in the 'permutations'.

```
def permute(lst):
    permutations = []
    permutations.append(lst)
    flag = True
    while flag:
        k = len(lst) - 2
        while k>=0:
            if lst[k] < lst[k+1]:
                break
            k -= 1
        else:
            flag = False
            break
        l = len(lst) - 1
        while l>k:
            if lst[k] < lst[l]:
                break
            l-=1
        lst[k], lst[l] = lst[l], lst[k]
        lst = lst[:k+1] + lst[len(lst)-1: k :-1]
        print('a')
        permutations.append(lst)
        print(lst, 'b')
    return permutations
print(permute([2,3,4,5])
```

I placed the print commands to check if for some reason the block is running twice but it doesnt. Instead of the final permutations being nested lists of all the permutations of [2,3,4,5] in order, it gives this:

```
[[2, 3, 5, 4], [2, 4, 5, 3], [2, 4, 5, 3], [2, 5, 4, 3], [2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 5, 4, 2], [3, 2, 5, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2], [3, 4, 5, 2], [3, 5, 4, 2], [3, 5, 4, 2], [4, 5, 3, 2], [4, 2, 5, 3], [4, 3, 5, 2], [4, 3, 5, 2], [4, 5, 3, 2], [4, 5, 3, 2], [5, 4, 3, 2], [5, 2, 4, 3], [5, 3, 4, 2], [5, 3, 4, 2], [5, 4, 3, 2], [5, 4, 3, 2], [5, 4, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: You issue likely lies with the fact that you append lst to permutations. Then you change lst by swapping values inside it with `lst[k], lst[l] = lst[l], lst[k]` . so you have effectively changed the last item stored in permutations. you should modify your code so that you only put an item in permutations once you have finished with it. And dont modify anything you already put in permutations.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you are appending `lst` to `permutations`, you're actually appending a reference to an object, rather than just the values of the object. As such, when you then change the values of `lst` later, `permutations` also changes.

`list.copy()` returns just the values of a list, decoupled from the original object. As such, if you replace your `permutations.append(lst)` lines with `permutations.append(lst.copy())`, you should get the desired output.

Demonstration of list reference effect vs copied list:

```py
>>> x = [1]
>>> y = []
>>> y.append(x)  # Directly append x to y
>>> y
[[1]]
>>> x[0] = 2
>>> y  # Changing x changed y
[[2]]
>>> y = []
>>> y.append(x.copy())  # Append copy of x to y
>>> y
[[2]]
>>> x[0] = 3
>>> y  # Changing x had no effect on y
[[2]]
```

Comment: I dont think thats the issue since the recreate lst in each iteration with `lst = lst[:k + 1] + lst[len(lst) - 1: k:-1]` which will create a new object. So all objecst in permutations will be unique oobjects

Comment: That's why it's only the edge cases that have the issue, and the whole list isn't the same set of values. I ran the code with this change prior to submitting my answer to ensure I wasn't mistaken.

Comment: I see your point oliver, the line of code thats the issue is `lst[k], lst[l] = lst[l], lst[k]` by the time they reach this line of code they have already appended `lst` to the permutations list. As such when this line runs it actually modifes the last entry in permutations. your answer will avoid this issue since permutations will have its own object based off list. I think the OP would be much better to refactor the code and instaed only store an item in permutations once they are finished modifying it

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I don't disagree that the code could be optimised, the intent of my answer was purely to note what was causing the bug that was being seen, and the logical extension of inbuilt functionality to avoid this.

Comment: ahh, thanks so much. Never knew changing the value of lst actually affects the original .append(lst). Imma go read up more about this. Thanks again!

Comment: @JosiahLee Please mark the answer as correct if your issue has been resolved - this helps people recognise which issues have been closed so they don't have to spend any more effort looking into them!